# Some say, obsessed

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The final answer consist of 11 letters and i'm looking for a name!

[image]

---

After you find the answer to the puzzle above, use this (to get the final answer):

**107 71**

---

**Hint1**

> In the example: How are the *2* x *5* grids related to the shapes? What can the *2* x *5* grid possibly represent?

**Hint2**

> Here are all 5 2x5 grids in horizontal position (in order)
>  [image]

Comment: Hmmmm, seems like rot13(vs jr ahzore gur 10 fdhnerf va gur 2*5 tevq sebz mreb gb avar, gur ahzoref gur juvgr fdhnerf ercerfrag pna or erneenatrq gb or gur fhz bs vagreany natyrf bs gur cbyltba gb juvpu gur 2*5 tevq pbeerfcbaqf.)

Comment: @JerryDean Go on ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The hidden name is:

> **NIKOLA TESLA**!

First, as noted by @JerryDean in comments, we can see from the Example puzzle that:

> If we number each of the cells in the 2x5 grids with digits from 0-9 in order along the rows, the digits in the *white* highlighted cells can be arranged so as to form **the sum of the internal angles** of the shape in the corresponding position in the diagram:
>
>  [image: Explaining the 2x5 grids]

Importantly, this teaches us that...

> ...we should interpret the grids in the first puzzle image as highlighting *digits that can be arranged to represent a specific angle, in degrees*.

Specifically, like so:

> [image: Interpreting puzzle grid 1]

Note next that...

> ...if you look at the equivalent rows of the *second* puzzle image, there are angles of these matching sizes!
>
>  [image: Matching angles in image 2]

Now look at the *third* puzzle image, and...

> ...overlaying the second image, see which digits these angles trace a path through:
>
>  [image: Tracing paths in image 3]

What are these? Well, put them all together and they look like...

> **Years**! Specifically, 1856-1943.
>
>  If we combine these with the additional numbers provided by the OP 107 71, and interpret these as a concatenated day and month number, we can form a pair of dates:
>
>  10/7/1856 - 7/1/1943
>
>  Which 11-letter person was born on 10/7/1856 and died on 7/1/1943? No doubt quite a few(!), but the most famous of these is probably the inventor and engineer, **[Nikola Tesla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikola_Tesla)**, a man [of many obsessions](https://www.britannica.com/story/nikola-teslas-weird-obsession-with-pigeons)!

Comment: Well done :) Everything looks good except a small typo at the end (birthyear)

Comment: @Prim3numbah Ah yes, fixed now!

Comment: ok this is genius i must say. hat tip!